# Python - short way to unpack list for string formatting operator?

Tags: python, string, tuples, formatting

Variations of the * or ** operators don't seem to work, unfortunately:

```
lstData = [1,2,3,4]
str = 'The %s are %d, %d, %d, and %d' % ('numbers', *lstData)
```

Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [format](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
str = 'The {} are {}, {}, {}, and {}'.format('numbers', *lstData)
```

see the docs for more details about possible formatting (floats, decimal points, conversion, ..).

Comment: You included a link to the documentation. Your aim is more true.

Comment: Any idea why sequence unpacking works for the 2nd argument only? Is the signature `format(positional, *args, *kwargs)`? It would be much more powerful if you could pass it `(*seq1, *seq2, *...)`. JavaScript ES6 supports it: `Math.min(...[...seq1, ...seq2])`.

Comment: @CodeManX From the docs, it's `str.format(*args, **kwargs)`. The arguments, as I understand it, are unpacked before they are passed to the function. You can unpack as many lists as you want, but they will all be assigned to the same argument list in the function. In the example above, `'numbers'` and '*listData' will both be passed into `*args` as part of the same tuple.

Comment: The way you would implement that JS example in Python is to create a function that takes one parameter: `min(*args)`.  You can call such a function by passing as many sequences to it as you want, like so: `min(*seq1, *seq2, *seq3)`

Answer (score 4):

```
s = 'The %s are %d, %d, %d, and %d' % tuple(['numbers'] + lstData)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> data = range(5)
>>> 'The {0} are {1}, {2}, {3}, {4} and {5}'.format('numbers', *data)
'The numbers are 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4'
```